# Oracle SQL to print rows of a particular column times

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help writing a SQL query (in Oracle).

I have this table:

```
 output_value | output_count
--------------+--------------
 abc          |            2
 def          |            3
```

Desired output:

```
abc
abc
def
def
def
```

Basically, I want the output to include each `output_value` value exactly `output_count` times.

Comment: Try this: https://www.folkstalk.com/2010/04/query-to-generate-duplicate-rows-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Do you need CTE in order to achive results:

```
create table t ( t  varchar2(50) , i  int );

insert into t values ( 'abc', 2);
insert into t values ( 'xyz', 3);

with cte (t,i) as (
   select t.t, t.i from t
   union all
   select cte.t, cte.i - 1 as i
   from cte
   where cte.i > 1
)
select cte.t
from cte
```

Result:

```
t   
--- 
abc 
xyz 
xyz 
xyz 
abc
```

Translated fro T_SQL to ORACLE syntaxt by @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I took the liberty to convert it to Oracle Syntax. It will required Oracle 11.2 though (won't work in earlier releases)

Comment: you forget varchar to varchar2 ;). Thanks!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, and what about [Do not use the VARCHAR datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#sthref77)?

Comment: `varchar` will automatically be converted to `varchar2` when you run the `CREATE TABLE`. That section you quote has been in there for over 20 years now (I think it goes back until version 6 or so). I don't believe any longer that Oracle will ever change that. The only possible trouble you might get if you save your DDL as SQL scripts, let them hang around until Oracle indeed changes that behaviour and you then run the CREATE on an empty database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. This quote is from 11g Release 1 (11.1) : [Do not use the VARCHAR datatype. Use the VARCHAR2 datatype instead.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)